# Is one Xeon core enough to run a general website on my VPS?

Tags: performance, vps, central-processing-unit, smp

I've purchased a VPS for dev work (at Linode) some time ago and am wishing to install NetBSD for the sake of experience, however its current support under the Xen hypervisor does not allow for SMP.

I would assume this would mean I could only use one core, am I correct? Or just one processor?

My content will contain a few not too intensive pages, although a lot of testing stuff and the odd script ran occasionally may be a bit intensive, I am wondering if a single Xeon core would be an alright solution for a small-medium dev website.

Don.

Comment: I will actually split the SMP part in to another question in a moment.

Comment: Just an fyi... VirtualBox or VMWare Player are excellent ways to build a basic test environment without the overhead of a VPS. It's a good way to learn without messing with a production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is a lack of SMP support, it means it will only support a single core/processor (basically very similar within the OS view).

As for whether that is sufficient for your actual needs, only you will be able to fairly judge that based upon your expectations. Core/CPU count alone is not the whole processing capabilities profile in most cases. There are a few other factors along CPU speed, memory, disk, IO, etc. which all come into play for most.